How to add legends and color code a list in python 3 jupyter
I am trying to create a scatterplot from a csv file and it worked but what I am trying to do now is to make a legend based on the list I made, which are the list of countries I made in the code, also I want a legend next to the graph. But most of the solutions I found online used libraries such as numpy and panda, but we are not allowed to use any libraries other than NamedTuple, List, matplotlib.pyplot and csv. Is there a way to do so? Below is a screenshot of the data:

**DATA DEFINITION**

from cs103 import *
from typing import NamedTuple, List
from enum import Enum
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##################
# Data Definitions

#The file we are using is called TENNIS_ACE_VS_WIN.csv and it includes rank, name, country name, country ID, ace percentages, and match
#won percentages. We chose to use name, country ID, ace percentages and matches won percentages to represent our information. They are
#crucial to our project because it is all the information we need in order to achieve our research question.

TennisPlayer = NamedTuple('TennisPlayer', [('name', str),
                                           ('country_id', str),
                                           ('ace_percentage', float), #represented as a percentage, (e.g., 20.5 for 20.5%), in range [0, 100]
                                           ('matches_won_percentage', float)])  #represented as a percentage, (e.g., 20.5 for 20.5%),
                                                                                #in range [0, 100]

#interp. a tennis player including their name, country ID, aces percentage, and matches won percentage
HURKACZ = TennisPlayer("Hubert Hurkacz", "POL", 24.94, 59.44)
FRITZ = TennisPlayer("Taylor Fritz", "USA", 18.47, 58.26)
KORDA = TennisPlayer("Sebastian Korda", "USA", 12.65, 53.61)


@typecheck
def fn_for_tennis_player(tp: TennisPlayer) -> ...:
    #template based on compound
    return ...(tp.name,
               tp.country_id,
               tp.ace_percentage,
               tp.matches_won_percentage)

# List[TennisPlayer]
# interp. a list of TennisPlayer representing the statistics of professional tennis players

LOTP0 = []
LOTP1 = [HURKACZ, FRITZ]
LOTP2 = [HURKACZ, FRITZ, KORDA]

@typecheck
def fn_for_lotp(lotp: List[TennisPlayer]) -> ...:
    #description of the acc
    acc = ...  #type: ...
    for tp in lotp:
        acc = ...
        
    return ...

LOC0 = []
LOC1 = ["POL", "USA", "RUS", "KAZ"]
LOC2 = ["CAN", "USA", "CHN", "JPN"]


@typecheck
def fn_for_loc(loc: List[countries]) -> ...:
    #description of the acc
    acc = ...  #type: ...
    for c in loc:
        acc = ...
        
    return ... 



# Consumed = ...



# # List[Consumed]
# # interp. a list of Consumed

# LOC0 = []

# @typecheck
# def fn_for_loc(loc: List[Consumed]) -> ...:
#     ... # choose which template body to use for List[Consumed]


###########
# Functions

countries = ['POL', 'USA', 'RUS', 'GER', 'KAZ', 'NED', 'GRE', 'AUS', 'BUL', 'CHN', 'FRA', 'ITA', 'SUI', 'CAN', 'ARG', 'SRB', 
             'DEN', 'NOR', 'ESP', 'CZE', 'GBR', 'FIN', 'AUT', 'RSA', 'JPN', 'CRO', 'COL', 'BRA', 'CHI', 'PER','HUN', 'BLR']

@typecheck
def main(filename: str, countries: List[str]) -> None:
    """
    Reads the file from given filename, analyzes the data, returns the result 
    """
    # Template from HtDAP, based on function composition 
    return show_scatterplot(read(filename), countries)
                   

    

@typecheck
def read(filename: str) -> List[TennisPlayer]:
    """    
    reads information from 'TENNIS_ACE_VS_WIN.csv' file and returns a list of TennisPlayer data
    """
    #return []  #stub
    # Template from HtDAP
    # loc contains the result so far
    lotp = [] # type: List[TennisPlayer]

    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(reader) # skip header line

        for row in reader:
            # you may not need to store all the rows, and you may need
            # to convert some of the strings to other types
            tp = TennisPlayer(row[1],              #just a str
                              row[3],              #just a str
                              parse_float(row[4]), #represents a float, in range [0, 100]
                              parse_float(row[5])) #represents a float, in range [0, 100]

            lotp.append(tp)

    return lotp



@typecheck
def find_avg_aces(lotp: List[TennisPlayer], loc: List[str]) -> List[float]:
    """
    Takes in a list of TennisPlayer and a list of countries and returns a list of the averages of all the aces of each country
    """
    #return [] #stub
    
    #initialize the values
    acc = []
    aces = 0.0 #type: float
    count = 0 #type: int
    
    #description of the acc
    for country in loc:
        for player in lotp:
            if player.country_id == country:
                aces = aces + player.ace_percentage
                count = count + 1
        if count == 0:
            avg_aces = 0
        else:
            avg_aces = aces / count
        acc.append(avg_aces)
        
    return acc
    

@typecheck
def find_avg_matches_won(lotp: List[TennisPlayer], loc: List[str]) -> List[float]:
    """
    Takes in a list of TennisPlayer and a list of countries and returns a list of the averages of all the matches won of each country
    """
    #return [] #stub
    
    #initialize the values
    acc = []
    matches_won = 0.0 #type: float
    count = 0 #type: int
    
    #description of the acc
    for country in loc:
        for player in lotp:
            if player.country_id == country:
                matches_won = matches_won + player.matches_won_percentage
                count = count + 1
        if count == 0:
            avg_matches_won = 0
        else:
            avg_matches_won = matches_won / count
        acc.append(avg_matches_won)

    return acc


def show_scatterplot(lotp: List[TennisPlayer], loc: List[str]) -> None:
    """
    Given a list of ace percentages and a list of matches won percentages, return a scatterplot graph.
    Colour code the points by country with 32 countries. 
    """
    # return None  # stub

    x_vals = find_avg_aces(lotp,loc)
    y_vals = find_avg_matches_won(lotp,loc)
    
    # set the labels for the axes
    plt.xlabel('Ace percentage %')
    plt.ylabel('Matches won percentage %')
    plt.title('Relationship betweeen Matches Won % and Ace %')

    # create the scatterplot
    #plt.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, s = 1)

    #Colourcoding points
    scatter = plt.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, s = 1, c = 'green')

    
    # show the plot
    plt.show()
    
    return None
    

# Examples and tests for main
start_testing()
expect(main("TENNIS_ACE_VS_WIN_empty.csv", countries), None)
expect(main("TENNIS_ACE_VS_WIN_test1.csv", countries), None)
expect(main("TENNIS_ACE_VS_WIN_test2.csv", countries), None)
summary()

start_testing()
# Examples and tests for read
expect(read("TENNIS_ACE_VS_WIN_empty.csv"), [])

expect(read("TENNIS_ACE_VS_WIN_test1.csv"), [TennisPlayer("Alexei Popyrin", "AUS", 13.39, 53.95),
        TennisPlayer("Maxime Cressy", "USA", 11.23, 52.43),
        TennisPlayer("Adrian Mannarino", "FRA", 10.42, 51.82),
        TennisPlayer("Marco Cecchinato", "ITA", 5.58, 48.05)])

expect(read("TENNIS_ACE_VS_WIN_test2.csv"), [TennisPlayer("Daniil Medvedev", "RUS", 14.72, 55.01),
        TennisPlayer("John Isner", "USA", 11.81, 53.18),
        TennisPlayer("Adrian Mannarino", "FRA", 10.42, 51.82),
        TennisPlayer("Denis Shapovalov", "CAN", 6.84, 49.11)])
summary()


#examples and tests for find_avg_aces
start_testing()
expect(find_avg_aces(LOTP1, LOC1), [24.94, 15.56, 0.0, 0.0])
# expect(find_avg_aces(LOTP2, LOC2), 15.56)
summary()

#examples and tests for find_avg_matches_won
# start_testing()
# expect(find_avg_matches_won(LOTP1, FRITZ), 58.26)
# expect(find_avg_matches_won(LOTP2, FRITZ), 55.935)
# summary()


#examples and tests for show_scatterplot
# start_testing()
# expect(show_scatterplot(LOTP1), None)
# summary()
main("TENNIS_ACE_VS_WIN.csv", countries)


Please read Asking about homework. Then if you still have a suitable post topic .... Please share data and not screenshots of it. For the future, please read How do I ask a good question? and note under 'Help others reproduce the problem' it emphasizes with bold .DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.Then for sharing data look at the ideas linked in the question here and the answers there.

I'm not entirely certain what you're asking, but it seems like you require a scatter plot that includes a legend. I made some adjustments to your scatter plot function so that it works with a list of NamedTuples. You're welcome to make additional modifications as needed.
from cs103 import *
from typing import NamedTuple, List
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##################
# Data Definitions

TennisPlayer = NamedTuple('TennisPlayer', [('rank', int),
                                           ('name', str),
                                           ('country_name', str),
                                           ('country_id', str),
                                           ('ace_percentage', float),
                                           ('matches_won_percentage', float)])

player1 = TennisPlayer(1, "Novak Djokovic", "Serbia", "SRB", 14.27, 81.67)
player2 = TennisPlayer(2, "Daniil Medvedev", "Russia", "RUS", 12.75, 77.88)
player3 = TennisPlayer(3, "Rafael Nadal", "Spain", "ESP", 10.94, 81.25)
player4 = TennisPlayer(4, "Alexander Zverev", "Germany", "GER", 11.61, 77.52)
player5 = TennisPlayer(5, "Stefanos Tsitsipas", "Greece", "GRE", 10.32, 74.72)
player6 = TennisPlayer(6, "Dominic Thiem", "Austria", "AUT", 10.08, 75.44)
player7 = TennisPlayer(7, "Matteo Berrettini", "Italy", "ITA", 9.54, 70.69)
player8 = TennisPlayer(8, "Diego Schwartzman", "Argentina", "ARG", 7.59, 69.16)
player9 = TennisPlayer(9, "Denis Shapovalov", "Canada", "CAN", 11.02, 67.31)

players = [player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, player6, player7, player8, player9]

def show_scatterplot(players: List[TennisPlayer]) -> None:
    ace_percentage = [player.ace_percentage for player in players]
    matches_won_percentage = [player.matches_won_percentage for player in players]
    country_names = [player.country_name for player in players]
    unique_countries = list(set(country_names))
    colors = plt.cm.get_cmap('tab10', len(unique_countries))

    for i, country in enumerate(unique_countries):
        country_players = [player for player in players if player.country_name == country]
        country_ace_percentage = [player.ace_percentage for player in country_players]
        country_matches_won_percentage = [player.matches_won_percentage for player in country_players]
        plt.scatter(country_ace_percentage, country_matches_won_percentage, color=colors(i), label=country)
    plt.xlabel("Ace Percentage")
    plt.ylabel("Matches Won Percentage")
    plt.title("Tennis Player Performance")
    plt.legend(title='Country')
    plt.show()

show_scatterplot(players)



What if I want to call the countries directly from the csv file, instead of defining the players individually, because we have 100 players and 32 countries in total

It's up to you to create a function that reads and converts CSV data into a list of NamedPlayers and passes it to the show_scatterplot() function. I do not have the CSV file, so I created some sample data.
